# apk and performance

Tags: android

after i develope my application i try to run my `apk` every thing works fine
and i go to the `setting` and take a screenshot of some `application` to show you

look at the picture
to know what i am taking about 
[image: http://im27.gulfup.com/daf61.png]

I would like help understanding exactly what information this screen gives to me and how to use it.

knowing that i use `android`

Comment: What you see there has nothing to do with performance but more about memory consumption... Do you want to know what the different fields under application settings describe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That screen tells you how much memory your app is consuming on the device.  This is how much space the user must dedicate from his device memory (could be 8GB, 16GB or more, depending on phone).

This is broken down in a few ways, to tell you how much space you app takes, and how much data (which can be stored separately - and can be cleared from the app, and by the user).

Don't forget to mark as correct.

Comment: But you never explained every single field in detail... or how they work.